# SharePoint Foundation 2010: no service for single sign on

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on

Alright, so I'm trying to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 with Single Sign-On. Almost everything works great, but when I go to the services section no services with the words "Microsoft Single Sign-on" are available to enable. I'm at my wits end here because every article touching the subject says to enable this service first. I'm running as a local administrator with a network account in AD.

Here are a few images with relevant info (can't insert into post due to lack of reputation/spam prevention):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK8yb.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, one more thing, so far I've installed SharePoint Foundation 2010 and met the requirements for said installation, and I can reach it from my browser, so it seems to be running fine.

Comment: Hi there. I'm currently working on a Sharepoint Foundation 2010 based intranet project and we got single sign-on to work with an Active Directory (Windows Server 2008 R2). When we installed Sharepoint Foundation with a network-administrator account, it automatically loaded all profiles from AD and People Picker gained visibility to ALL AD profiles, groups and so. We also validated password changes and new users creation (in AD) and all changes became visible to our Sharepoint Foundation 2010 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Sign On (SSO) has been replaced in Sharepoint 2010 by a new service which is called: Secure Store Service (SSS).

This should get you in the right direction:

[how to create configure consume sharepoint 2010 secure store in business connectivity services](http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/how-to-create-configure-consume-sharepoint-2010-secure-store-in-business-connectivity-services/)

Comment: Thanks, great to know I've fallen into the right rabbit hole now at least, but it seems I've burrowed into another problem: SSS isn't showing up in the Service Applications/Services on server pages. It does look like BDC is there, however, and I'm thinking that SSS may only available for the full SharePoint Server....

Comment: You're right. According to this page: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx Security Store Service is standard/enterprise sharepoint feature. Haven't played with the foundation so i assumed wrong.